# Approval page is truncated

Tags: marketing-cloud

When opening an e-mail to approve I only see the first inch of the content.  Everything else is gone/truncated. Why do I get this behavior? How can I see the full message?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a custom email template. If so i would check the CSS.

A picture / screenshot would help to add more details to your problem